# Android, SQLite rawQuery does not send any results after select a item in a listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to display a selected item in a listview, populated with SQLite in another activity, but  when i make the rawQuery, using the _id row identifier to show it the item in the other activity, but does not send any results, leads me to the other activity, but did not shows anything in the xml layout, i don't know if i'm doing correctly my declaration of rawQuery, this is my search code and my handler to show it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_details);

    courseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("COURSE_ID", 0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.title, emp.instructor, emp.length, emp.rating, emp.topic, emp.subject, emp.description, mgr._id managerId, mgr.title managerTitle FROM courses emp LEFT OUTER JOIN courses mgr ON emp.title = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 
            new String[]{""+courseId});


    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            tTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTitle);
            tTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            tInstructor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tInstructor);
            tInstructor.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instructor")));

            tLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tLength);
            tLength.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("length")));

            tRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tRating);
            tRating.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("rating")));

            tTopic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTopic);
            tTopic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("topic")));

            tSubject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tSubject);
            tSubject.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject")));

            tDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDescription);
            tDescription.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return; 
}}
```

this is the class that shows the listview and performs the Intent:

```
public class lay_main extends ListActivity {
public ListView list;
public DBHelper myAdap;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
public Cursor cursor;
DBHelper Context;
DBHelper ArrayList;

//adapter cAdapter class
protected ListAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_main);  

    collectXML();
    setupDataBase();
    setupAdapter();            
}      
private void collectXML() 
{
     list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);  

}

public void setupDataBase() {
    myAdap = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    myAdap.insertCourses();     

}

public void setupAdapter()
{
if(myAdap.getCourses()!=null)
    {
    adapter = new  cAdapter(this, R.layout.list_courses, myAdap.getCourses());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }   
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
 {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseDetails.class);
        Courses course = (Courses) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("COURSE_ID", course.title);
        startActivity(intent);  
 }}
```

really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your data over an bundle:

```
Bundle sendBundle = new Bundle();
    sendBundle.putString("COURSE_ID", course.title); //or use putInt if course.title is int type
    //sendBundle.putInt("COURSE_ID", course.title);
    Intent i = new Intent(lay_main.this, CourseDetails.class);
    i.putExtra("testBundle", sendBundle);
    startActivity(i);
```

and recieve it like:

```
Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("testBundle");
    if (receiveBundle != null){
        String courseId = receiveBundle.getString("COURSE_ID");     
        //or int courseId = receiveBundle.getInt("COURSE_ID");     
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your quickly answer, but this sends me the error: "Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception" later: " unable to parse 'Culture Change: Creating A Climate Of Care...' as integer

Comment: Let test your Course_ID that your list received by code below:
`String courseId = getIntent().getString("COURSE_ID");
Log.v("your TAG","courseId :"+ courseId);`

Comment: i think I do not explain well, in the intent, i need to send the row _id (int) but on the next screen I get always the same item number 1 on the listview, I don't get the other items, my question is about how I can properly declare the intent to send the row _id and show it in the next screen, because always i just receive the first item of the listview, not the others, Greetings

Comment: really would appreciate your help Vin. how can i do with super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id); Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseDetails.class); Courses course = (Courses) adapter.getItem(position); intent.putExtra("COURSE_ID", course.title); startActivity(intent); , in the part course.title, i don't want use title, i need implement getColumnIndex, because always i receive the same item in the list

Comment: in my code i use a cursor and put a long value as an id. I hope that codes below are helpful with you.
`yourCursor.moveToPosition(position);
selectionIndex = yourCursor.getLong(yourCursor.getColumnIndex("COURSE_ID"));`
use putLong to pass selectionIndex.